# Как лучше разбить диск при установке Линукса

Tags: linux, hdd, linux-mint, partition

Использую Linux Mint KDE более года и остался очень доволен. Единственное неудобство - не могу перейти в режим гибернации. Полазив по форумам нашел что для этого необходимо сделать свап раздел с объемом не меньше чем объем РАМ.

Так как придется переустановить систему, хотелось бы для начала спросить у опытных линуксоводов - стоит ли разбить диск для использования Линукса в качестве домашнего декстопа (фильмы, интернет-сёрфинг, Вайн для пары игрушек, VirtualBox для пары виртуалок для экспериментов, плюс очень желательна гибернация) и если да то каким образом лучше всего разбить?

Посоветуйте из вашего опыта.

Comment: Про гибернацию — логично. Стоит ли — полностью вам принимать решение. Наш опыт субъективен и никак не относится к вашему опыту — у нас другое железо, другие потребности и задачи.

Comment: dreadangel, пожалуйста, не меняйте в корне содержимое вопроса, лишая смысла данные вам ответы. задавайте, пожалуйста, **новый** вопрос, с новой формулировкой.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin по сути - ответ на свой вопрос(даже в исходном варианте) я получил, за что ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ спасибо сообществу. Но так как администрация увидело в изначальной формулировке вопроса - опросник - за что искренне извиняюсь за использованную стилистику, увы, русский язык не мой родной язык - я попытался изменить формулировку вопроса, но не меняя его сути. Если сплоховал - примите мои искрение и глубочайшие извинения. Однако вопрос я считаю отвеченным - всем ещё раз - Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый лучший вариант - вынести /home на отдельный диск.
Если нет такой возможности, то для домашней системы годятся варианты с "/ + /home + swap" или "/ + swap"

Comment: а как это сделать? просто при разбивке разбить на 3 раздела - рут, свап и просто 3ий раздел - но как сделать чтобы 3ий раздел был именно home?

Comment: @dreadangel: http://www.mintlinux.ru/blogs/razmyshlizmy-62/ustanovka-linux-mint.html - вот здесь с картинками

Answer (score 1):

совет из опыта:

если установка производится на «чистый» диск (или при установке можно удалить всё прежнее содержимое), то **новичку** будет лучше довериться в вопросе разбивки диска программе-инсталлятору.

а **опытный** пользователь уже и сам знает — как следует использовать диск под **его собственные** нужды.

Answer (score 1):

Разбивал на 3 части Корневая для подкачки и home,читал на форумах это самый оптимальный вариант!

Answer (score 0):

Swap-раздел необязателен, можно настроить так, чтоб образ памяти сохранялся в файл на диске, а не в swap-раздел.

По поводу разбития, я лично разбиваю на несколько разделов (`/boot`, `/var`, `/tmp`, `/home`), но если это домашняя система, и у вас нет особого опыта использования Linux, я бы не заморачивался.

Answer (score 0):

разбивайте исходя из Ваших потребностей. Ваши потребности не указаны. Опишу какие могут быть варианты
`/swap` - раздел подкачки, придерживайтесь правила что он равняется объему Вашей оперативной памяти
`/home` - отличная практика выносить домашний каталог. В случае каких либо проблем Вам не придется настраивать окружение.
`/var/www` | `/var/work` - привел пример когда монтирование раздела происходит не в корень. Как вариант работая директория может быть монтируемым раделом
`раздел ntfs` | `раздел без файловой системы` - есть смысл зарезервировать место для другой ОС, если Вы планируете развернуть **DualBoot**. В этом случае есть практика выносить загрузчик на отдельный радел `/boot`, но это не обязательно.